# Binwalk error on update ubuntu jammy jellyfish

Tags: 12.04, apt, package-management, updates, python

After installation. I run command `binwalk` and it shows me following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/binwalk", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('binwalk==2.3.3', 'binwalk')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 656, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1453, in run_script
    exec(code, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/binwalk-2.3.3-py3.10.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/binwalk", line 2, in <module>
    from binwalk.__main__ import main
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'binwalk.__main__'
```

Comment: There is no `binwalk` command "after installation" in Ubuntu 22.04. What does the 12.04 tag mean?

Comment: @Pilot6 what i am saying is, After updating my old ubuntu to new i got above error on running command `binwalk` . i already had binwalk installed on my system.

Comment: This means that `binwalk` is incompatible with python installed in 22.04.